# Storing image in XML

Tags: xml, xsd

Is there a way to store image data in XMl (XSD)?

Answer (score 3):

You could encode it using Base64 and store the result.

Comment: how does the Base64 implemented?

Answer (score 3):

I really don't recommend to do this but if you really have to you can just encode your image in Base64 and save it to the XML File and decode it where you want to use it.

I have seen this in some Software projects but if there is a way to avoid this please don't do it! That's not what XML is made for.

Comment: what other approach do you suggest I should adopt? I was thinking of having xml image data, so as I can send across using JMS messaging and decode it to display using TIBCO queue.

Comment: Totally agree.  I would do something like Firefox extensions where a ZIP file contains the XML file that references other (image) files in the ZIP file.

Comment: @dwyane is there a chance for you to just send an URL to the Image through JMS? So that you have a place where all your images can be downloaded for a certain period of time. And the receiver could then pull the image itsself. Maybe you could explain your "overall"-case a bit more so that i can understand what you are using it for.

Comment: i am creating a business process using tibco designer as a middleware and jms messaging as a message middleware. The business process basically retrieve criminal records from an external web service(created manually by me using JAVA PROGRAMMING) through xml and i wish to include the images of criminals in the xml while transferring the XML using SOAP. The data in the XML is then stored in a database.

Comment: Okay you could then actually store the image as base64 record in the XML file. But i think there is a place, a computer where your external webservice runs. If you have control over that computer, why not make Java Servlet, or a simple HTTP Server where you can retrieve your images through a simple URL you sent through soap? That would be "cleaner" than sending the data inside xml. And it would be a better performance also, because you can get the data first, display it and just display a "image is loading..." message or something. If you sent it in xml you have to wait for the entire data

Answer (score 2):

You could base64 encode it (xsd:base64binary).

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is a way. Although if you are talking about bitmaps (not vector-based images) it would make no sense at all.